# One-liner to extract digits from a string

Tags: perl

I am learning Perl regex, and I am trying to extract digits from a string, e.g.

```
my $text = "abc000142gh";
```

i.e. I would like to extract `000142` as a string in a scalar variable.

I have tried:

```
my $digits = $text ~= /(+d)/;
my $digits = $text ~= m/(+d)/;
my $digits = $text ~= m/(+d)/g;
my $digits = $text ~= /(+d)/g;
```

but none of them seem to work. Is there a way to do this with a one-liner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
my $text = 'abc000142gh';
my ($digits) = $text =~ /(\d+)/;
```

The differences:

1. quotes around the string (not needed, but prefered).
2. $digits in brackets to enforce list context. See [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop) for details.
3. The binding operator is `=~`, not `~=`.
4. `\d` means a digit, `d` stands for itself.
5. `+` (repetition) is used after the symbol to repeat, not before.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that putting the assignment in list context is important because matches return a list of matches, and list assignment to a scalar results in the number of matches, not the matches themselves.  Thus, putting digits into a list context will allow it to receive the first match found, not just the number of matches.

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not compile. There are a few issues here.

- You have forgotten to quote your string

  ```
  my $text = 'abc000142gh';
  ```
- You have the regex binding operator (`=~`) the wrong way around,
- forgotten the backslash for the `\d`
- and the quantifier (`+`) in front of it

  ```
  my $digits = $text =~ /(\d+)/;
  ```

---

Now to answer your question You need to enforce list context. The match returns a list, and since you have `$digits`, which is a scalar, the list gets transformed to its number of elements.

```
(my $digits) = $text =~ /(\d+)/;
```

It does not matter if you put the [`m`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/m.html) in front of the regex because it is implicit with any `/foo/` expression.

---

Take a look at these things:

- [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is very handy to evaluate regexes
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. Sorry I forgot to quote the string.